# How to find point location after transformation using warpperspective opencv with modified image size?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, vision

Here is my use case. I have 2 images. I am transforming image 2 onto image 1. Image 1 can be bigger or smaller than image 2. I use homography matrix with warpperspective to transform image 2 on image 1.

Image 2 original size M2, N2 and image 1 size is M1, N1. Now after transformation image 2 will be of size M1, N1 as defined by me so that both images are of same size. Now my question is where is point (x,y) from original image 2 now in the transformed image 2.

I understand the equation of matrix multiplication with x,y but I am not sure how to handle this image size change.

Comment: at the matrix multiplied version of the point. The size change is part of the transformation.

Comment: @Micka   So if I want to find the location of a point (x,y) from image2 after transformation based on size change, how do I find it? what is the equation. I have my image transformed. I need the equations so that I can find the new point in the transformed image 2

Comment: M*(x,y,1) and if the result is not 1 in the z coordinate: divide it by z

Comment: @Micka This is fine if both image1 and image2 are of same size. In my case image1 size is M1,N1 and original image2 size is M2,N2. After transformation image2 size is M1,N1. How do I account for this difference in size to find new point in transformed image2?

Comment: please share your code... If the warping has the size change included already, then the transformation already has it included, which means you dont have to do anything else than applying the transformation to a point, if you instead do some magic and cropping etc, then you'll have to show or explain what you are doing.

Comment: homography, mask = cv2.findHomography(points1, points2, cv2.RANSAC)


height, width = im1.shape[:2]


im2reg = cv2.warpPerspective(im2, homography, (width, height), cv2.INTER_CUBIC)


@Micka how is this width and height variable internally handled since homography is found with just points1 and points2 and no information on size is given there? How do we find where a new point is on im2reg given (x,y) in im2

Comment: points1 are in a different scale than points2, so the homography includes the scaling. The actual image size doesnt play any role, you can warp the images to any image size you like to. There is no additional scaling. Try  (width*2, height*2), you will see the same image with some additional space to the right and to the bottom

Comment: ok. to understand more clearly, even if I do width/2 and height/2 will it be handled? loss of information?

Comment: you'll see only half of the transformed image then (if the image was completely filling the output image with output size (width, height)).

Comment: the location calculation is same irrespective of width height parameters. if size is reduced, then it might be out of the image bounding box in this new scenario. Is this what you are saying?

Thanks I would like to know why it is so? Maybe I am not understanding the reasoning behind why width height have no factor on transformation location identification

Comment: yes, your transformation tells you where the image is placed (and how it is deformed) on a canvas of size (width,height). If your canvas is too small, you'll lose information. If your canvas is too big, you'll get a lot of black space in the image.